# how to hide content after first read more link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to hide the rest of the paragraphs after the 'read more' link. As of now the the read more link gets appended to 'EACH' p element. I am relatively new to jQuery if you can point to what i am doing wrong that would be helpful.

**[Here is my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuwnm289/)**

**jQuery**

```
$('.BlockContent p').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    var link = $('#NewsContent .p-name a').attr("href");

    if (txt.length>5) {
        $(this).html('<span>'+txt.substring(0,5)+'&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="'+link+'"> Read More</a>');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="BlockContent" id="NewsContent">

  <p><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"></p>

  <h1 class="p-name"><a href="testPost.html">Page Title</a></h1>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam in odio mi. Fusce varius urna quis sem viverra id laoreet sem imperdiet. Morbi ultricies varius tortor, in congue ipsum facilisis ut. Suspendisse potenti. Nam ut eros quis orci eleifend rutrum vestibulum adipiscing nisl. Morbi mauris dui, iaculis consequat auctor in, auctor vel velit. Mauris lacinia adipiscing sapien, vel mollis massa pulvinar et. Curabitur eu urna venenatis nisi rhoncus eleifend.</p>

   <p>Nam dapibus lectus ac libero aliquet id malesuada tortor accumsan. Mauris lacus orci, euismod ac vehicula nec, scelerisque non tortor. Praesent quis odio a elit congue luctus. Aliquam ultricies, massa quis gravida tincidunt, justo mi scelerisque lectus, fringilla hendrerit tortor metus quis tellus. Suspendisse sit amet felis eu erat mollis rhoncus at non ligula. Fusce odio est, consectetur sed scelerisque quis, rhoncus ac lectus. Donec accumsan viverra eros, et vulputate augue laoreet et.</p>
   <p>Nam dapibus lectus ac libero aliquet id malesuada tortor accumsan. Mauris lacus orci, euismod ac vehicula nec, scelerisque non tortor. Praesent quis odio a elit congue luctus. Aliquam ultricies, massa quis gravida tincidunt, justo mi scelerisque lectus, fringilla hendrerit tortor metus quis tellus. Suspendisse sit amet felis eu erat mollis rhoncus at non ligula. Fusce odio est, consectetur sed scelerisque quis, rhoncus ac lectus. Donec accumsan viverra eros, et vulputate augue laoreet et.</p>
    <p>Nam dapibus lectus ac libero aliquet id malesuada tortor accumsan. Mauris lacus orci, euismod ac vehicula nec, scelerisque non tortor. Praesent quis odio a elit congue luctus. Aliquam ultricies, massa quis gravida tincidunt, justo mi scelerisque lectus, fringilla hendrerit tortor metus quis tellus. Suspendisse sit amet felis eu erat mollis rhoncus at non ligula. Fusce odio est, consectetur sed scelerisque quis, rhoncus ac lectus. Donec accumsan viverra eros, et vulputate augue laoreet et.</p>

   </div>
```

Comment: so the fiddle looks ok.

Comment: what actually u need ?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: `$('p:gt(0)').hide();`

Comment: i want to hide the the rest of the paragraphs after i insert the read more tag. right now it adds 'read more' to each `p` tag @SajadKaruthedath @rahuldesai

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
$('.BlockContent h1 ~ p').hide().first().show().each(function () {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    var link = $('#NewsContent .p-name a').attr("href");

    if (txt.length > 5) {
        $(this).html('<span>' + txt.substring(0, 5) + '&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="' + link + '"> Read More</a>');
    }
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nuwnm289/2/

---

It will hide all `p` elements folowing the `h1` tag, except the first one. On that first one it will run your code for adding the link.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to only show the first article snippet and hide the rest.

All you need is the following changes to your code to make it work. I added an i parameter to your each function to use as an iterator and and extra if then statement to hide the other p tags.

Javascript: jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/nuwnm289/6/

```
$('.BlockContent p').each(function(i) {//add the i variable to count iterations

    var txt = $(this).text();


    var link = $('#NewsContent .p-name a').attr("href");

    if (txt.length > 5) {


        $(this).html('<span>'+txt.substring(0,5)+'&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a  href="'+link+'"> Read More</a>');

    }

    //if i is greater than one
    //or in other words you have looped
    //past the first .BlockContent p tag
    if(i > 1){

        //hide the other paragraphs
        $(this).hide();

    }
});
```

Comment: this sort of works but it hides the read more link. @larrylane

Comment: Right now the fiddle I posted doesn't hide the read more link after your first paragraph. Can you please explain exactly which read more link you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution to make your "read more" links work.

```
$('.BlockContent p').each(function() {

    var _this = this;
    var txt = $(this).text();
    var link = $('#NewsContent .p-name a').attr("href");

    if (txt.length>5) {
        $(this).html('<span>'+txt.substring(0,5)+'&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="'+link+'" class="show-more"> Read More</a>');
    }

    $(_this).find(".show-more").click(function (event) {

        $(_this).html(txt);

        event.preventDefault();

    });

});
```